# mix cobol with c++/C

Tags: c++, cobol, gnucobol

I tried to mix COBOL code with C++, but i not have success :(

I see this topic in IBM forum: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v111v131/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cbl.doc/PGandLR/tasks/tpsub17.htm  ( Calling between COBOL and C/C++ programs )

But, when I go to build this code, I receive several  a lot of errors from linker :(

So, what I can do to build this code, using OpenCobol?

Comment: https://thenextweb.com/finance/2017/04/25/banks-should-let-ancient-programming-language-cobol-die/#.tnw_TZuilN1M

Comment: @EJP I did not make the edit you're referring to: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6632553/2. Also: take your random complaints elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IBM docs are specific to their compiler and OS. Try this instead

[OpenCobol wiki](http://www.opencobol.org/modules/bwiki/index.php?cmd=read&page=UserManual%2F2_3)